# How to fix "Method or data member not found" on AllowEdits button

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I'm trying to make a button to lock/unlock edits and adittions in a form and subform.

In my main form CONSULTAS PEDIDOS, I have two subforms CONSULTAS PRODUCTOS y LOTES. When I click on BLOQUEAR button, I want to turn on/off AllowEdits and AllowAditions properties in CONSULTAS PEDIDOS and CONSULTAS PRODUCTOS depending on the caption text, but  I want keep editing and adding records in LOTES subform.

I tried this code:

```
Private Sub bloquear_Click()
With Me.bloquear
 If .Caption = "Unlock" Then
    Me.AllowAdditions = True
    Me.AllowEdits = True
    Me.CONSULTA_PRODUCTOS.AllowAdditions = True
    Me.CONSULTA_PRODUCTOS.AllowEdits = True
      .Caption = "Lock"
 Else
    Me.AllowAdditions = False
    Me.AllowEdits = False
    Me.CONSULTA_PRODUCTOS.AllowAdditions = False
    Me.CONSULTA_PRODUCTOS.AllowEdits = False
      .Caption = "Unlock"
      Me.Refresh
 End If
End With
End Sub
```

I tried the code only with main form CONSULTAS PEDIDOS and it works, but when I added CONSULTA PRODUCTOS clauses, Access reports me *The expression On Load you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: Method or data member not found*. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm a absolute beginner writing code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either I am not understanding your question or the code you presented is not the one with problem. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks, fluidguid, it was a issue writing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to follow subform container control name with reference to Form class because those are properties of form object, not container control.

```
    Me.CONSULTA_PRODUCTOS.Form.AllowAdditions = False
    Me.CONSULTA_PRODUCTOS.Form.AllowEdits = False
```

Comment: Thank you so much June, that was the problem.